Is sahaja samadhi the requirement for Moksha?
I may be wrong, but there doesn't seem to be a consensus in the traditions I have studied on this subject. Some say that nirvikalpa samadhi leads to moksha/liberation and others say that only with sahaja samadhi can one become free.

This is also my observation, there is different advice from different teachers. It is my observation that the advice differs based on whom they are teaching and how they have realised the truth. This means different variants of samadhi are advised.
To elaborate further, it is knowledge (jnana) which brings moksha. In Advaita Vendata of Sri Shankaracharya ji it is specifically intuitive knowledge.
Consequently, samadhi itself is not moksha, but a state in which a type of knowledge is known, as it were. That knowledge is Atmajnana (knowledge of the Atman) or specifically the nature of Atman, which are sat chit ananda.
The point of samadhi, of all types, is that it stills the mind and leads to direct intuitive knowledge of Atman. Atman is Brahman, and so knowing Brahman one verily becomes Brahman (liberated whilst living).
However, keep in mind that samadhi is a passing activity or state. One cannot remain sat in meditation all of one's life. So samadhi comes and goes in general, whereas Atman does not come and go. Atman is persistent and eternal. It is seeing or knowing of the qualities of Atman persistently in a moving world, that leads to moksha.
Consequently, persistently knowing Atman is moksha. This moksha is described by some gurus as a form of samadhi, because it is similar in nature. It is a pointer to Atman. That Atman which is seen momentarily in samadhi is the same as that which is known persistently in moksha. This is because the knowledge in samadhi and the knowledge which comes with moksha are the same. Both are knowledge of Atman and lead to liberation.

He who knows the Supreme Brahman verily becomes Brahman. In his family no one is born ignorant of Brahman. He overcomes grief; he overcomes evil; free from the fetters of the heart, he becomes immortal. Mundaka Up 3.2.9

